# unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 40 bytes Error

Tags: laravel

I Want to run my application in localhost with `php artisan serve` but I get this Error `unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 40 bytes` where is my problem?

Comment: Do you use it out of the box? Or in which code part does the error appear? It's a bit difficult to help you without some code or more informations.

Comment: how I can explain my problem?I just get this Error in all page of application @Stony

Comment: try `php artisan serve -vvv`. Afair this should display a more verbose output for your error and you can probably find the cause.

Comment: @Tschitsch I test it but get just this Error

Comment: Then you probably should dig into some advanced debugging techniques for php, otherwise its really hard to help you, sorry. Try to introduce a custom error_handler in order to get some detailed output first. I assume that your application relies on some serialized representation of something, but we cannot know.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? There are some changes after 5.6.30 that may cause this. Check the upgrade guide for more info https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade#upgrade-5.6.30

Comment: @AdrianHernandez-Lopez version of my laravel is 5.6,this work before but Now I get this Error

Comment: @AdrianHernandez-Lopez your answer help me I Created new laravel and copy this .env file to this project,I'm deleting .env file and use old version file

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I got the same error, when I upgrade a Laravel 5.5 app to 5.6. The error comes form the `EncryptCookies`-Middleware.

Delete the cookies in your browser and/or clear your session-files in your Laravel app.

Answer (score 92):

You have to set a news Key Generate because

```
php artisan key:generate
```

After that test again to run the Laravel Application

```
php artisan serve
```

Comment: Why is this necessary?

Comment: because the cookies linked with the applications key, if you change the key its like your app has no cookies again

Comment: Will it invalidate session of all user whos session stored in database ?

Answer (score 27):

I've faced same problem. I frequently faced this problem in Homestead-vagrant environment.
To solve this issue in Laravel 5.4,5.5,5.6 or more:

```
php artisan config:clear

php artisan view:clear

php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: php artisan config:clear may or may not be needed depending on your set up. I didn't need that one, but I did need the next 2.

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error a couple of days ago when I pushed a production update to my Laravel project from [Envoyer](https://envoyer.io).

**Immediate fix:**
I tried to rollback to the previous commit but the issue persisted which means the issue was originating from the client side, cookies probably. I tried removing cookies and the issue was gone.

Later, I spent a lot of time looking for this issue but got nothing until I faced this issue again today with another deployment and i found this article on [Laravel news about the security fix](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-6-30) 5.6.30 update. I was able to identify that this issue occurs if i try to deploy previous (< 5.6.30) version of the laravel  v5.6.26 for a project which was already using > v5.6.30 and cookies were already created ( not serliazed) which when <5.6.30 version of the framework tries to unserlize results in error because they're not properly serealized.

- Installing laravel/framework (v5.6.26)
  Loading from cache

[From the upgrade guide:](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade#upgrade-5.6.30)

> Configuring Cookie Serialization Since this vulnerability is not able
> to be exploited without access to your application's encryption key,
> we have chosen to provide a way to re-enable encrypted cookie
> serialization while you make your application compatible with these
> changes. To enable / disable cookie serialization, you may change the
> static serialize property of the  App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies
> middleware:

I was able to fix this issue permanently by clearing cache of composer so forcing it to load latest version of the framework instead of falling back to cache.

Comment: _I was able to fix this issue permanently by clearing cache of composer_ what was the command you used to do that? `composer dump-autoload`?

Answer (score 5):

Just Inspect the element in Browser, and go to application tab and select cookie and delete that all cookie. That's It.

Answer (score 3):

In App\Exceptions\Handler under render function use this snippet, it will reset browser cookie.

```
if (str_contains($exception->getMessage(), 'unserialize')) {
    $cookie1 = \Cookie::forget('laravel_session');
    $cookie2 = \Cookie::forget('XSRF-TOKEN');

    return redirect()->to('/')
                 ->withCookie($cookie1)
                 ->withCookie($cookie2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case I did removed my `composer.lock` and did a `composer install` and voila...

```
$ cd project_root
$ rm composer.lock
$ composer install
```

Comment: Work for me in Laravel 5.5

Comment: it's never a good idea to just delete composer.lock. This may work when u're working with a hello world app on your desktop, but not on a production app. See more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49593368/766570

Comment: I do that all the time. If you have pinned the versions correctly in composer.json it shouldn't be a problem at all. at least from my experience.

Comment: Normally in composer.json you don't specify exact versions of dependencies but rather a min version and above. Without composer.lock, running composer install will install the latest stable version of a particular dependency which might no longer work with your app.

Comment: I know and I agree. And normally I won't log in to production and delete `composer.lock` or any file and do composer install.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was trying to decrypt a hash with an wrong function.

I was creating encrypt using encryptString()

```
$hash = Crypt::encryptString('secret');
```

but I tried to decrypt using decrypt()

```
$value = Crypt::decrypt($hash);
```

the correct way is

```
$value = Crypt::decryptString($hash);
```

So when you encrypt using `Crypt::encrypt()` you must decrypt it using `Crypt::decrypt()`, and for `Crypt::encryptString()` use `Crypt::decryptString()`

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this issue when I happened to update my composer. 
If you put

```
protected static $serialize = true;
```

inside App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies, the old cookie will break your system. So to prevent this, either you have to clear the cookie, or just don't unserialize the decrypted cookie.

I made a workaround for this:
Inside vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php
Above this line of decrypt() function:

```
return $unserialize ? unserialize($decrypted) : $decrypted;
```

add:

```
try {
            return $unserialize ? unserialize($decrypted) : $decrypted;
        } catch (\Exception $e){
            return $decrypted;
        }
```

This might be ugly, but you can temporarily put it there until you think the old cookies has gone.

Comment: Interesting. But why not just remove the old cookie in the browser?

Comment: @molerat sure you can just clear your cookies but if your site has been public to many users then probably you don't want to interrupt their experience.

Comment: Good point. Wasn’t thinking about that because my environment is still all local and private at this point.

Comment: your fix won't work when you update your laravel, since the update will wipe our your changes (inside the vendor directory). This answer works for localhost hello world apps, but production apps

Comment: @abbood yes, that's why i said it's a temporarily fix until the old cookies from your users gone. Or else you can override this method to make this a permanent fix.

Answer (score 1):

In my case happened during local development.
The steps that caused the problem was:

1. I upgraded the laravel up to 5.8 on a seperate branch.
2. I switched into an another branch having laravel 5.2 (in my case I had to review a PR)

I also was logged in in my app and hence there was a session cookie as well. In that case I just cleared the browser's cookies and got fresh ones.

In firefox can be done via visiting then select `about:preferences#privacy` and select the appropriate option.

An anothwer aproach to diagnose the issue it to open a private firefox window or use chrome's cognito mode.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is clear the configuration cache file

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Then create a new key for the application

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Finally, restart the server.. I hope it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was related to route cache

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Answer (score -2):

yeah, for localhost you can just delete cookies, but for production put this in your error handler so users would not see whoops :

```
if (strpos($exception->getMessage(), 'unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 40 bytes') === 0) {
    unset($_COOKIE['laravel_session']);
    unset($_COOKIE['XSRF-TOKEN']);
    
    setcookie('laravel_session', null, -1, '/');
    setcookie('XSRF-TOKEN', null, -1, '/');
    
    abort(200, '', ['Location' => route('frontend.home')]);
}
```

tested for laravel 5.6.