# Laravel 5.5: Using ckFinder 3 - Error unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 40 bytes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ckfinder

I use ckFinder3 in my Laravel 5.5 project. When I try to choose an Image, I got this error.

[Here's the error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgxuh.png)

I don't know what's happening...please advise. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 40 bytes Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51817913/unserialize-error-at-offset-0-of-40-bytes-error)

Comment: @Christophvh I tried the solutiion, but still not working...