# unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 40 bytes

Tags: laravel

This Error comes When i try to server site login.[image]

How to solve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 40 bytes Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51817913/unserialize-error-at-offset-0-of-40-bytes-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel made a change to the way it handles cookies from V5.6.30 to improve security.  It may be that you are trying to decrypt something that isn't serialized or vice versa.

First, **Delete the cookies in your browser and/or clear your session-files in your Laravel app**.

Or, within the middleware `app\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php`, you can flip it to test:

add: `protected static $serialize = true;`

This is a pretty common question - you can search stack overflow for similar answers if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set a news Key, use the following command:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

After that test again to run the Laravel Application

```
php artisan serve
```

See the similiar question: [unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 40 bytes Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51817913/unserialize-error-at-offset-0-of-40-bytes-error)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the cookies in your browser and/or clear your session-files in your Laravel app.

I got the same error, when I upgrade a Laravel 5.5 app to 5.6. The error comes form the EncryptCookies-Middleware.

Answer (score 0):

This type of issue normally rise when you downgrade your Laravel version and a quick solution is I just clear my laravel and browser cache and it will work fine for me. Browser cache clear is mostly important.