# how to fix this unserialize(): ErrorCache/FileStore.php:187

Tags: laravel, caching

I have problem with my apps in production, it send me error message sometimes

like this

> unserialize(): Error at offset 3719157 of 3719158 bytes(0) =>
>   /home/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/FileStore.php:187

how to fix it?

my web apps used Laravel Framework 5.6.39, 
deployed in shared hosting

try with change permission folder with 777 in storage/logs, still not fix my problem

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843543/unserialize-error-at-offset-0-of-40-bytes/54843921#54843921   This might be your issue.  Also - regenerate your key.

Comment: regenerate app key in production?  will this make problem sir ?

Comment: any solution? facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

We saw the same error recently after deploying our app.

We were able to resolve it by deleting the `storage/framework/cache` folder.