# unserialize(): Error at offset 16383 of 16384 bytes

Tags: php, laravel

I Want to run my application in localhost with php artisan serve but I get this Error unserialize(): Error at offset 16383 of 16384 bytes where is my problem? Please help me anyone? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52056432/12503693

Comment: Yes, I tried this way but it is not ok.

Comment: Is it a fresh laravel app or did you upgraded laravel version? Give some context information.

Comment: Yes I used laravel version 7.30.6.

Comment: Yes, It is right. I tried this ways but it is not ok.

Comment: Try to clear cookies or open your website in incognito mode.

Comment: Yes, I also tried this way. But it is not ok .